# Labeled circle Point in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I'm using the package `circuitikz` which branches off `TikZ` for drawing circuits. I have the following code:

```
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (4,3)
    to[short](4,4)
    to[R=$R_2$,v_>=$v_2$](0,4)
    to[short](0,0)
    to[battery=$V_S$](8,0)
    to[short](8,3)
    to[R=$R_3$,v_>=$v_3$](4,3)
    to[short](4,2)
    to[R=$R_1$,v_>=$v_1$](0,2)
;
\end{circuitikz}
```

which produces the following,

[image]

But I would like to be able to place circled labels at points like such,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circuitikz **IS** tikz, with a lot of extra shapes defined.  OTOH, `to` doesn't pay attention to edges, so you have to specify the anchor point.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\node[draw,circle] (A) at (4,4) {A};
\node[draw,circle] (B) at (8,3) {B};
\draw (4,3)
    to[short] (A.south)
    (A.west) to[R=$R_2$,v_>=$v_2$](0,4)
    to[short](0,0)
    to[battery=$V_S$](8,0)
    to[short](B.south)
    (B.west) to[R=$R_3$,v_>=$v_3$](4,3)
    to[short](4,2)
    to[R=$R_1$,v_>=$v_1$](0,2)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

Personally, I would have gone with:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (4,3)
    to[short,-o] (4,4) node[above] {A}
    to[R=$R_2$,v_>=$v_2$](0,4)
    to[short](0,0)
    to[battery=$V_S$](8,0)
    to[short,-o](8,3) node[above] {B}
    to[R=$R_3$,v_>=$v_3$](4,3)
    to[short](4,2)
    to[R=$R_1$,v_>=$v_1$](0,2)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: second demo]